# Why does my query return slightly different result, which is SUM of premium

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, reporting-services

In a first query I am using `LEFT JOIN` to return months even though there is no data in it. But seems like it doesn't work.

So in the second query I decided to use `RIGHT JOIN tblCalendar` in order to return months without data. But why there are different results for each month ?

```
;with cte_TopClasses AS 
( 
    select  
        b.YearNum,
        b.MonthNum,
        REPLACE(ClassCode,'+','') + ' - '+ QLL.Description as Description,
        SUM( Premium) as NetWrittenPremium
    from
        tblCalendar b  
    left join
        ProductionReportMetrics prm on b.MonthNum = Month(prm.EffectiveDate) 
                                    and b.YearNum = YEAR(EffectiveDate)     
                                    and prm.EffectiveDate >= DateAdd(yy, -1, DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))) 
                                    and prm.EffectiveDate <= EOMONTH(GETDATE())  
                                    and CompanyLine = 'Ironshore Insurance Company' 
                                    and LineOfCoverage NOT IN ('SSP Commercial General Liability', 'SSP Property')
    left join
        NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote Q on prm.NetRate_QuoteID = Q.QuoteID
    left join
        NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat QL ON Q.QuoteID = QL.QuoteID    
    LEFT JOIN   
        (SELECT * 
         FROM NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat_Liabi nqI 
         JOIN 
             (SELECT LocationID as LocID, MAX(ClassCode) as ClCode 
              FROM NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat_Liabi  
              GROUP BY LocationID) nqA ON nqA.LocID = nqI.LocationID AND nqA.ClCode = nqI.ClassCode ) QLL ON QLL.LocationID = QL.LocationID 
where
    (b.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 and b.MonthNum >= MONTH(GETDATE()) + 1)
    or (b.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE()) and b.MonthNum <= MONTH(GETDATE())) 
group by
    b.YearNum, b.MonthNum, ClassCode, QLL.Description
    ) 
    /*And this is that crazy final select statement from Richards (Stackoverflow) */
SELECT *
    FROM    (
            SELECT  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Description] DESC) AS Rank, * 
            FROM    cte_TopClasses
            WHERE   Description IN  (
                                    SELECT  [Description]
                                    FROM    (
                                            SELECT  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(NetWrittenPremium) DESC) AS [Rank], [Description], SUM(NetWrittenPremium) AS total
                                            FROM    cte_TopClasses
                                            WHERE [Description] IS NOT NULL
                                            GROUP BY [Description]
                                            ) BB
                                    WHERE [Rank] <= 10
                                    )
            ) AA
ORDER BY YearNum, MonthNum
```

In the next query, all I did is basically instead of `tblCalendar` in a first `SELECT` statement I used `RIGHT JOIN tblCalendar` in a final `SELECT` statement
After I dump it into SSRS and break down by month, it gives me different result for some reason

```
    ;with cte_TopClasses
AS  ( 
select  
        YEAR(prm.EffectiveDate) as EffectiveYear,  --adding Effective because of SSRS repeating column and it gives me a shit
        MONTH(prm.EffectiveDate) as EffectiveMonthNum,  --adding Effective because of SSRS repeating column and it gives me a shit
        REPLACE(ClassCode,'+','') + ' - '+ QLL.Description as Description,
        SUM( Premium) as NetWrittenPremium
--FROM      tblCalendar b 
FROM         ProductionReportMetrics prm

--LEFT JOIN     ProductionReportMetrics prm ON b.MonthNum=Month(prm.EffectiveDate) AND b.YearNum = YEAR(EffectiveDate)  
--          AND prm.EffectiveDate >=DateAdd(yy, -1, DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))) AND prm.EffectiveDate <= EOMONTH(GETDATE())  AND CompanyLine = 'Ironshore Insurance Company' 
--          AND LineOfCoverage NOT IN ('SSP Commercial General Liability','SSP Property')
LEFT JOIN   NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote Q ON prm.NetRate_QuoteID = Q.QuoteID 
            AND LineOfCoverage NOT IN ('SSP Commercial General Liability','SSP Property')
LEFT JOIN   NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat QL ON Q.QuoteID = QL.QuoteID    

LEFT JOIN   (SELECT * FROM NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat_Liabi nqI 
            JOIN ( SELECT LocationID as LocID, MAX(ClassCode) as ClCode 
            FROM NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat_Liabi  GROUP BY LocationID ) nqA 
            ON nqA.LocID = nqI.LocationID AND nqA.ClCode = nqI.ClassCode ) QLL 
            ON QLL.LocationID = QL.LocationID 

--WHERE ( b.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE())-1 and b.MonthNum >= MONTH(GETDATE())+1 ) OR 
--                  ( b.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE()) and b.MonthNum <= MONTH(GETDATE()) ) 
GROUP BY    YEAR(prm.EffectiveDate) ,
            MONTH(prm.EffectiveDate), 
            ClassCode,      
            QLL.Description
    ) 
    /*And this is that crazy final select statement from Richards (Stackoverflow) */
SELECT Rank, b.YearNum,b.MonthNum, Description,NetWrittenPremium  
    FROM    (
            SELECT  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Description] DESC) AS Rank, * 
            FROM    cte_TopClasses
            WHERE   Description IN  (
                                    SELECT  [Description]
                                    FROM    (
                                            SELECT  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(NetWrittenPremium) DESC) AS [Rank], [Description], SUM(NetWrittenPremium) AS total
                                            FROM    cte_TopClasses
                                            WHERE [Description] IS NOT NULL
                                            GROUP BY [Description]
                                            ) BB
                                    WHERE [Rank] <= 10
                                    )
            ) AA RIGHT JOIN tblCalendar b ON b.YearNum = AA.EffectiveYear AND b.MonthNum=AA.EffectiveMonthNum 
            WHERE ( b.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE())-1 and b.MonthNum >= MONTH(GETDATE())+1 ) OR 
                    ( b.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE()) and b.MonthNum <= MONTH(GETDATE()) ) 

ORDER BY YearNum, MonthNum
```

Everything is the same till part circled in red. Why would that be?

[image]

Try #1

```
    ;with cte_TopClasses
AS  ( 
select  
        YEAR(prm.EffectiveDate) as EffectiveYear, 
        MONTH(prm.EffectiveDate) as EffectiveMonthNum,  
        REPLACE(ClassCode,'+','') + ' - '+ QLL.Description as Description,
        SUM( Premium) as NetWrittenPremium

FROM         ProductionReportMetrics prm

LEFT JOIN   NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote Q ON prm.NetRate_QuoteID = Q.QuoteID 
            AND LineOfCoverage NOT IN ('SSP Commercial General Liability','SSP Property')
LEFT JOIN   NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat QL ON Q.QuoteID = QL.QuoteID    

LEFT JOIN   (SELECT * FROM NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat_Liabi nqI 
            JOIN ( SELECT LocationID as LocID, MAX(ClassCode) as ClCode 
            FROM NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat_Liabi  GROUP BY LocationID ) nqA 
            ON nqA.LocID = nqI.LocationID AND nqA.ClCode = nqI.ClassCode ) QLL 
            ON QLL.LocationID = QL.LocationID 
GROUP BY    YEAR(prm.EffectiveDate) ,
            MONTH(prm.EffectiveDate), 
            ClassCode,      
            QLL.Description
    ) 
SELECT TOP 10 Description, SUM(NetWrittenPremium) AS NetWrittenPremium, EffectiveYear,EffectiveMonthNum
FROM cte_TopClasses RIGHT JOIN tblCalendar b ON b.YearNum = EffectiveYear AND b.MonthNum=EffectiveMonthNum 
            WHERE ( b.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE())-1 and b.MonthNum >= MONTH(GETDATE())+1 ) OR 
                    ( b.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE()) and b.MonthNum <= MONTH(GETDATE()) ) 
GROUP BY [Description],EffectiveYear,EffectiveMonthNum
ORDER BY SUM(NetWrittenPremium) DESC
```

[image]

Comment: so the final stuff from "richards" on stackoverflow.  You know that makes no sense right? There are easier ways to do that on sql server (`TOP X` command is one) What was it supposed to do?

Comment: Also you should never use `SELECT * ...`.  Never. Not Ever.  Don't do it. List the fields.  This will be slow and cause bugs.  Don't do it.

Comment: The reason I've done this way its because in SSRS I have to Filter records by SUM(NetWrittenPremium) DESC.  Because the totals was incorrect. Its another topic for that problem. And there are some workarounds but I tried and it didnt help. 
So Richard wrote the query the way that its just selecting top 10 for each month.

Comment: ok. Thanks for advice about SELECT * ...

Comment: Sure but if you want the top 10 for each month you don't need rank() and two query -- user a group by, a sum() and the TOP 10 qualifier.  get rid of two levels of sub-queries.  This is like the one thing sql server does better than other platforms.

Comment: also it is easier to support if you have the fields -- think about us reading the code, we have no idea what fields you want with you put `*`

Comment: I would love to get rid of two levels of sub-queries but...Unfortunately my reputation is not 446K like yours :), Its kinda complicated for me

Comment: you will get there.

Comment: Thanks for encouragement, but how would I approximately rewrite final select statement?

Comment: I put it in an answer (also my rep is only 43k, but thanks for multiplying it by 10 :D)

Answer (score 0):

Top 10 descriptions by sum in sql server.

1) get the descriptions and sum:

```
SELECT [Description], SUM(NetWrittenPremium) AS total
FROM ct_TopClasses
GROUP BY [Description]
```

2) take the top 10

```
SELECT TOP 10 [Description], SUM(NetWrittenPremium) AS total
FROM ct_TopClasses
GROUP BY [Description]
ORDER BY SUM(NetWrittenPremium) DESC
```

This is a bit simpler, yes?

Comment: Maybe this will help you to understand the problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209657/how-to-pivot-this-query-and-display-only-top-10-records-filtered-by-sumnetwritt

Comment: this returns the sum of premium in the total column.  kinda my point, this is functionally the same.

Comment: I just did your way, query and the result are  above

Comment: Wow, I really did over complicate this a little (maybe a lot!). I must have seen `rank`, and didn't try to think of at other way to do this. Don't forget to filter out the records where the description is `NULL`.

Comment: @Oleg -- you are doing something different in your example above -- you are grouping by description, year, month.  This is not what I do, I group by description.  I'm not sure of the results you want so I don't know if this is what you need or not.